# Two Mixins with same name function Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, mixins

I have this problem with vuejs and mixin.
I have a component that has 2 Mixin:

```
 export default {
 ...
 mixins:[Mixin1, Mixin2],
 ..
}
```

Both Mixins have a function named "delete", so if in my component I have a method like:

```
methods:{
 deleteObj(){
    this.delete()
 }
}
```

I don't know which one function I call.
I know the simplest way is call with a different name the functions but is there a way to specify which mixin to use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you duplicated definitions in methods in mixins, the last mixin will override the previous definitions. In your case `this.delete()` must called from `Mixin2`.

But if have lifecycle hooks like `mounted`, `created` ... those will be executed one by one in vuejs. There are some strategies followed for merging, vuejs itself you can found more at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html